# How do I use a command name with spaces? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to have a command name with spaces, however I can't find a way to do that. I want the bot to respond to "Am I right lads or am I right lads?" with "You are right lad!".

Obviously this won't work

```
@client.command()
async def Am I right lads or am I right lads?(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("You are right lad!")
```

I tried using an alias but that didn't work either.

```
@client.command(aliases=["Am I right lads or am I right lads?"])
async def airloairl(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("You are right lad!")
```

Answer (score 0):

•Hey buddy unfortunately there is no such way to make a command with spaces in discord.py

•You **CANNOT** use `.`,`,`,`-` or even`?` to make it simple as well

•The only option you have is to use underscore(`_`)
and make it `am_I_right_lads_or_am_I_right_lads`

•But I would not recommend it as it is too long and probably no one will use it

```py
@client.command(aliases=["amirightlads"])
async def airl(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("You are right lad!")
```

•This is just a suggestion but just to make your commands easier to use on both Mobile and PC try making your commands case insensitive by replacing your

```py
client=discord.Bot(command_prefix="whatever_your_prefix_is",....)#the "..." is the other stuff like intents
```

to

```py
client=discord.Bot(command_prefix="whatever_your_prefix_is",case_insensitive=True,...)#the "..." is the other stuff like intents
```

Answer (score 0):

As defined in the discord.py api *documents. You can't. Although you can use positional arguments in command (As shown below in code). But Command itself can only have one word.

```
@client.command()
async def check(ctx, am, i, right):
  # Code goes here
  await ctx.reply("You are right lad!")
```

Then you can maniplulate these arguments as you like whether its conditions or storing in a file/dictionary.
*
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the arguments of the `airloairl` function.

Example:

```
@client.command(aliases=["Am I right lads or am I right lads?"])
async def Am(ctx,*,text):
  if text == " I right lads or am I right lads?":
        await ctx.reply("You are right lad!")
```

With this solution you **WILL NOT** be able to add any more arguments

Answer (score 0):

Rather then trying to do this in a command, I think its easier to just do this in an event where you wouldn't have to do ?am_i_right_lads etc etc but rather just say it in chat which causes an event.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == 'am i right lads or am i right lads?':
        await message.channel.send('You are right lad!')
```

I think this makes it a lot easier and it means you don't have to type in the exact command whenever you want the bot to say this so I hope this helped.

Good luck with your project! I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You can use on_message function

```py
async def airl(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("You are right lad!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx,message):
   messagel=message.lower()
   if messagel.content=="am I right or am I right lads?":
       airl(ctx)
   bot.process_commands(ctx)
```